# Programmatically scroll NSScrollView to the right

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

Everything is in the title; I want to programmatically scroll an `NSScrollView` to the right so I can see the end of my document.

I tried this :

```
let width = scrollView.frame.size.width
let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
let toRight = CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(toRight)
```

But it didn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: what is the content size of the scrollView

Comment: It is (935.0, 619.0)

Comment: does your scrollable width fit to that point ? can you try to directly set contentOffset property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work by scrolling the content view :

```
scrollView.contentView.scrollPoint(NSPoint(width, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let toRight = CGRect(x: width, y: 0, width: 0, height: height)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(toRight)
```